# How to invoke virtual method using reflection in c#

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

Here I've mentioned a class from CsvHelper.CsvReader,

```
public class CsvReader : IReader, IReaderRow, IDisposable
{
    ....
    ....
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetRecords<T>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<object> GetRecords(Type type);
}

public class Test
{
....
}
```

In this, I would like to invoke GetRecords method using reflection in C#,

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                {
                    HasHeaderRecord = true,
                    MissingFieldFound = null,
                    HeaderValidated = null,
                };

CsvHelper.CsvReader csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(binaryData), config);

//direct all
var result = csvReader.GetRecords<Test>();
```

now, I need to call this GetRecords using reflection. So, I've tried as below,

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = csvReader.GetType().GetMethod("GetRecords");
```

while calling this methodInfo, it throws "ambiguous match found".

Kindly help me on this, how to resolve this issue.

EDIT:

```
Type genericType = typeof(Test);//it will be dynamic to pass

MethodInfo methodInfo = csvReader.GetType().GetMethod("GetRecords", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<object>) });
        
var result = await methodInfo.InvokeAsync(genericType, new[] { csvReader });
```

So that, I'm unable to Invoke it since methodInfo getting as null.

Comment: @McNets code throws error while reading this "MethodInfo methodInfo = csvReader.GetType().GetMethod("GetRecords");" line itself.

Comment: is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32252760/5174469) helpful ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56083156/3270427

Comment: `.GetMethod(nameof(CsvReader.GetRecords), new[] { typeof(Type) });` if you want the second overload.